# Android Studio editor: how to disable blue popup of import suggestions

Tags: android-studio, editor, auto-import

Apparently with the latest upgrade to Android Studio (2.2.2 built 18 oct 2016), it now displays blue popup hints (AKA Auto Import Suggestions) in the editor, hovering over the line where you have your cursor if there is a syntax or other error in the line. In the snip below, the cursor is under the carat.

[image]

How can I disable these? They are blocking the code I'm trying to read !

The do disappear after a few seconds but every time I move the cursor they reappear. Horribly annoying.

The old version produced a yellow hint popup, but only if you hover the mouse over the line with an error. (This version still has that behavior.)

Comment: Wish I could upvote this about 200 more times

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go To **Preferences** > **Editor** > **General** > **Auto Import**

In **Java** section uncheck **Show import popup** and **Show import suggestions for static methods and fields**.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks. I didn't pay close enough attention to the type of error to realize it was about "import". Good job !  By the way, I think I only want to uncheck "show import popup" - I still want to get the suggestions, just not with the automatic popup.

Comment: Note: this solution avoids the popup but, then, you have to manually create each "import". Easy - just press alt-enter - but another step when writing code.